# Multi domains for Magento 2

Tags: magento2, url, multidomain, multi-website, domain

My website's default URL is: **dev4.wetag.ca**

I added a second website to my Magento with the code: **wetag_us**
I want to give it this URL: **dev4.wetag.me**

SO I changed it's url in the admin panel configuration, and following tutorials I added these lines in .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

SetEnvIf Host .*dev4.wetag.me.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=wetag_usa
SetEnvIf Host .*dev4.wetag.me.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website



RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

I also tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)dev4\.wetag\.me
RewriteRule .* – [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:wetag_usa]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)dev4\.wetag\.me
RewriteRule .* – [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
```

none of them seemed to work, when i visit the new domain it says:

> This site can’t be reached
>   dev4.wetag.me’s server IP address could not be found.
>   Search Google for dev4 wetag me
>   ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

I also tried to park  **dev4.wetag.me** on **dev4.wetag.ca** through **WHM**, but still not working.

Am I missing something? Please help! 
Ps. I'm not a virtual machine or anything its on live server, CentOS.

Thank you !

Comment: Share DNS settings

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you would have some DNS management that needs to be done.  If you post your DNS settings for both of the domains, we can debug or eliminate it as the issue.

---

**Double-check**

Notice the **wetag_us** here:

> I added a second website to my Magento with the code: **wetag_us**

but you have **wetag_usa** everywhere else:

> SetEnvIf Host .*dev4.wetag.me.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=wetag_usa

and

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)dev4.wetag.me
>   RewriteRule .* – [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:wetag_usa]